# XSLT split keeping a section static

Tags: xslt, split, static

I am trying to split the file below to 3 items each and also keep the last section the same. Additionally, I also need to Header block that appears at the beginning with each split (except the last).

Input file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Root>
<List>
        <Header>
                <test1>a</test1>
        </Header>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>
                <Number>1</Number>
            </ItemNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>
                <Number>2</Number>
            </ItemNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>
                <Number>3</Number>
            </ItemNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>
                <Number>4</Number>
            </ItemNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>
                <Number>5</Number>
            </ItemNumber>
        </Item>
</List>
<List>
    <EOF MaxMsgPerFile="3" >
    </EOF>
</List>
</Root>
```

Here is what I have tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


  <xsl:variable name="tag">
  <xsl:value-of select="/*/*/EOF/@MaxMsgPerFile"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
<xsl:copy>


    <xsl:for-each select="List[not (EOF)]/Item[position() mod $tag = 1]">
        <List>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Header"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::Item[position() &lt; $tag]"/>
        </List>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:copy-of select="List[EOF]"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get everything I wanted but I cant see the Header appearing at each split

Here is what is expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
<List>
        <Header>
                <test1>a</test1>
        </Header>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>
                <Number>1</Number>
            </ItemNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>
                <Number>2</Number>
            </ItemNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>
                <Number>3</Number>
            </ItemNumber>
        </Item>
</List>
<List>
            <Header>
                <test1>a</test1>
        </Header>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>
                <Number>4</Number>
            </ItemNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>
                <Number>5</Number>
            </ItemNumber>
        </Item>
</List>
<List>
    <EOF MaxMsgPerFile="3">
    </EOF>
</List>
</Root>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:variable name="groupSize" select="List/EOF/@MaxMsgPerFile" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="List/Item[position() mod $groupSize = 1]">
            <List>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../Header | . | following-sibling::Item[position() &lt; $groupSize]"/>
            </List>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy-of select="List[EOF]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```