# Simple way to group XML elements using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having an inbound document which contains some tags in a carton. Like,

```
<root> 
  <shiping id="foo"> 
    <carton> 
      <tag no="1" weight="10" mandatory="False">4</tag>  
      <tag no="2" weight="20" mandatory="True">13</tag>  
      <tag no="3" weight="50" mandatory="True">35</tag>  
      ......
    </carton> 
  </shiping> 
</root>
```

I have around 2000 such rows of tag(s).  I need to create small packs of 10 tags each in the carton. example,

```
<root> 
  <shiping id="foo"> 
    <carton> 
     <newpack no="12" weight="20">
       <tag no="1" mandatory="False">4</tag>  
       <tag no="2" mandatory="True">13</tag>  
       <tag no="3" mandatory="True">35</tag>  
      ......

     </newpack>
     <newpack no="12" weight="20">
       <tag no="11"  mandatory="False">4</tag>  
       <tag no="12"  mandatory="True">13</tag>  
       <tag no="13"  mandatory="True">35</tag>  
      ......

     </newpack>
    </carton> 
  </shiping> 
</root>
```

I tried it using XSLT, but I am somehow stuck wih trying to insert the "newtag" element and also close it at the end of the 11th position in a for loop. Here is what I tried,
http://xsltransform.net/gWcEhWB

Would any expert have an advice for me perhaps ?
Appreciate your help
regards
Candy

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45743623/3016153

Comment: I stumbled on this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55928836/xslt-xml-table-records-pagination?noredirect=1&lq=1. I was able to reuse the same approach on the above link from @michael.hor257k and the previous question.